# Replace mutiline strings in a file using python

Tags: python-2.7

I need replace multiple lines from a file with another set of multi lines, the replacement could be either shorter or longer in length. I used the following code but doesn't help.

String to capture

s_string="""(r
"setVariableActions" : [ {
      "description" : null,
      "exitCodes" : null,
      "notificationOption" : "Operation Failure",
      "notifyOnEarlyFinish" : false,
      "notifyOnLateFinish" : false,
      "notifyOnLateStart" : false,
      "status" : "Failed",
      ......}]"""

r_string="""r_string= r""" "setVariableActions" : [ {
      "description" : null,
      "exitCodes" : null,
      "notificationOption" : "Operation Failure",
      "notifyOnEarlyFinish" : false,
      "notifyOnLateFinish" : false,...."""

data=re.sub(r_string,s_string,data)
print(data)

```
  "
```

Answer (score 0):

string replace worked to solve this issue.
act_var='''""setVariableActions" : [ { "description" : null, "exitCodes" : null,...'''
replace_var='''""setVariableActions" : [ { "description" : null, "exitCodes" : null, ....'''

data=data.replace(act_var,replace_var)